# How to turn connection pool fault-tolerant in Quarkus?

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, quarkus, agroal

I'm working on a **quarkus** (2.16.5) application with MSSqlserver and **Jtds** driver.

Unfortunately, although I've configured *validation-query* and *background-validation* properties, I'm still getting connections in invalid state when network goes down and recovered few moments later.

In order to improve the reliability, **There is a way (config) to prevent quarkus application from using invalid connections and remove them from the pool?**

Error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid state, the Connection object is closed.
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.checkOpen(JtdsConnection.java:1744)
    at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.prepareStatement(JtdsConnection.java:2448)
    at io.agroal.pool.wrapper.ConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(ConnectionWrapper.java:658)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
```

DataSource configuration:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=5
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=20
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.initial-size=5
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.acquisition-timeout=10
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.background-validation-interval=5
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.validation-query-sql=SELECT 1
quarkus.transaction-manager.default-transaction-timeout=600

quarkus.datasource.db-kind=other 
quarkus.datasource.username=sa
quarkus.datasource.password=123456
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sqlserver-local/MYDB;
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.driver=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
```

POM's dependencies

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-elytron-security-ldap</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-narayana-jta</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JDBC extension for the official driver sets an `ExceptionSorter` to flush those connections faster. That mechanism could be use in an extension for the custom `JTDS` driver

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-mssql</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, you can reduce the background validation interval.

Please note that there is no way to ensure 100% reliability in these scenarios, as a connection can pass validation and still fail right after that.

Comment: Thanks @Barreiro. I'll try to reduce the background validation interval, configure other properties like connection lifetime and idle removal interval.

Comment: I look at MSSQLExceptionSorter and MsSQLAgroalConnectionConfigurer implementations and it seems simple. There is a way to use a custom version of them in my quarkus application without create a new extension? I think I miss some configuration because my implementation of configurer is not "recognized" or "loaded" by agroal

Comment: the only reason to use Jtds driver is the requirement to authenticate providing username and password from ActiveDirectory. The official driver does not allows it.

Answer (score -1):

I have the following settings in production and it works when our db cluster fails sometimes:

```
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-lifetime=5M
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.idle-removal-interval=3M
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.validation-query-sql=select 1
```

You can also test it by yourself, by starting the application and the db via docker, then kill the db and restart the db and see if your application still works.